# How to disable elastic scrolling in nested scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a `tableView` containing various views, where some might be subclass of `UIScrollView`. In some cases, such as when user drags on nested `scrollView`, which is currently at the top, it correctly scrolls the main `tableView`, however the rubber band effect is applied also to the nested subView.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? So that rubber band effect is applied only to the main `scrollView`, but the nested one stays as it is?

EDIT: Preferably while keeping `bounces` se to `true`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `bounces` to your scroll view subclasses at init or setup. Btw, Apple does not recommend nested scroll views, be careful with simultaneous gestures handling.

Comment: What if I wan to keep bounces set to true? Yep, simultaneous gestures are pain in the ass.

Comment: You can try to disable the child gestures if parent table view scrolled to bottom (from any value to bottom, not checking only scroll at bottom). You can achieve this with a centralized scroll delegate.

Comment: I've used the bounces solution after all, as I didn't find any viable solution.
Still, the UI should somehow inform the user there's nothing more to scroll to, or the other way - let him know that there is more content hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`bounces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces) on the inner scrollview to `false`:

```
nestedScrollView.bounces = false
```

Comment: What if I want to keep bounces set to true?